# How to return selected item from KivyMD list?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm trying to write code that will return the number of the item that is clicked on in a list but I don't know what needs to go after lambda x:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem

KV = '''
ScrollView:

    MDList:
        id: container
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(20):
            self.root.ids.container.add_widget(
                OneLineListItem(text=f"Single-line item {i}", on_press=lambda x: print("item number"))
            )

Test().run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common issue when defining a lambda in a loop. The fix is to create a new argument to the lambda that is the current value of the loop variable. Try replacing:

```
OneLineListItem(text=f"Single-line item {i}", on_press=lambda x: print("item number"))
```

with:

```
OneLineListItem(text=f"Single-line item {i}", on_press=lambda x, item=i: print("item number", item))
```